# How to reference project in a different folder in ASP.net vNext

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

Let's say I have a project (project1) that lives in `[solution folder]\project1\`. There's no problem adding a new project (project2) in `[solution folder]\project2\` and referencing it as a dependency in project1's `project.json` with the line below:

```
"project2": ""
```

However what if I move project2 to a different (file system instead of solution) folder such as `[solution folder]\lib\project2\`? How do I add the reference in this case?

====================================

Just want to share a new tip: 
If you have a project in a subfolder `e.g. [solution folder]\lib\project1\` and want to reference another project located in the solution folder `e.g. [solution folder]\project2\`, make the following change to the global.json:

```
{
    "sources": [""]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a global.json file to the solution folder with the following text in it:

```
{
    "sources": ["lib"]
}
```

THT,
Bart

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it doesn't seem to work. Did you test your solution in VS14 CTP2?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Did you add the folder where the other project is to the sources in global.json next to the sln file?

Comment: I did, but still I'm unable to add project2 as project1's dependency in the project.json. If it works for you, would you mind attaching your sample (the whole solution folder) or uploading it somewhere?

Comment: Oh, it works, I had to type the dependent project name manually because VS doesn't support IntelliSense for this in project.json yet unfortunately.

Comment: Everything works fine on my end, you can find the sample here https://github.com/desdesdes/stackoverflow25369699

Comment: @DesDesDes, it works fine for me too. But the project name just can't show up in IntelliSense if it's under a different folder. Hope the later VS version is able to support that. Thanks a lot for your help!